# How to update pin information on google map using xamarin

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin

It is necessary to replace the direct connection to the database with [API](http://194.141.118.43:3001/stations).

I use this code to directly connect to MySQL db and change pin information:

```
 public async void DatabaseConnection(List<CustomPin> pins)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "server=192.168.0.1;uid=user;port=4444;pwd=pass;database=dbName;";
        MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM sel_alert_level s;";
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, Conn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                    int codeNum = myReader.GetInt32(4);
                    int level = myReader.GetInt32(3);
                    int mapCode = myReader.GetInt32(0);

                    foreach (var item in pins)
                    {
                        if (item.CodeNum == codeNum)
                        {
                            item.AlertLevel = level;
                            item.CodeNum = codeNum;
                            item.MapCode = mapCode;

                            //await DisplayAlert("Alert", mapCode.ToString(), "ok");
                        }
                    }
                    //await DisplayAlert("Database Connection", "Connected .." + Environment.NewLine + myReader.GetInt32(0) + Environment.NewLine + myReader.GetString(1) + Environment.NewLine + myReader.GetString(2) + Environment.NewLine + myReader.GetInt32(3) + Environment.NewLine + myReader.GetInt32(4), "OK");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                myReader.Close();
                Conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Database Connection", "Not Connected ..." + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

With this code I successfully update the pin information.
[image: Screenshot]

Now I create the same method with API Response and what to do the same like `DatabaseConnection();` just try to update the information, but not work for me :(

```
 public async void APIConnection(List<CustomPin> pins)
    {
        try
        {
            WaterBindingData waterData = await _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint));


            foreach (var water in waterData.WaterStation.Stations)
            {
                foreach (var item in pins)
                {
                    if (item.CodeNum == water.CodeNum)
                    {

                        item.AlertLevel = water.AlertLevelStation;
                        item.CodeNum = water.CodeNum;
                        item.MapCode = water.MapCode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Data Alert", "Error:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

I not have any errors here. `waterData` come with the data, but data not changed in the pins.. I don't know why...
[image: screenshot 2]

And Now my information are not changed ..
[image: Screenshot3]

```
MapCode and other variables not changed.
```

I call this two methods in the constructor like that:

```
 DatabaseConnection(customMap.CustomPins);
 APIConnection(customMap.CustomPins);
```

So... When I start the project I receive message like this:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. (MSB3276) (MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS)
```

And I check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but I not have `properties` option, because I use mac. I have only `options` on the projects.

**Is it possible that this does not change the content in the pins аnd what would be the reason it didn't work ?**

I checked the if statement in the loop and she work:

[image: screeenshooot]

Comment: have you debugged your code?  Are you sure that the code in the `foreach` loops and `if` statement is actually executing?

Comment: I update the question, see the last screenshot. The if statement work fine..

Comment: The only different between sql and webapi is that one is asynchronous method and the other is not .

Comment: Is there a way to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an asynchronous method , I suggest you try to assign `customMap.CustomPins` in `APIConnection` method .

Something like that

```cs
//constructor
List<CustomPin> pins = xxxxx;
APIConnection(pins);

 public async void APIConnection(List<CustomPin> pins)
    {
        try
        {
            WaterBindingData waterData = await _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint));


            foreach (var water in waterData.WaterStation.Stations)
            {
                foreach (var item in pins)
                {
                    if (item.CodeNum == water.CodeNum)
                    {

                        item.AlertLevel = water.AlertLevelStation;
                        item.CodeNum = water.CodeNum;
                        item.MapCode = water.MapCode;
                    }
                }
            }

             customMap.CustomPins = pins;    //assign the value in this line
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Data Alert", "Error:" + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, give me example in the constructor with List<CustomPin> pins = xxxxx;

I use:  CustomPin pin1 = new CustomPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(41.59043006333251, 24.766286971618303),
                Name = "Xamarin",
                Label = "р. Бяла",
                Address = "гр. Смолян",
                CodeNum = 1,
                AlertLevel = 2
            };

Comment: After I use: customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> {
                pin1, pin2... ... and after that I use customMap.Pins.Add(pin1);
            customMap.Pins.Add(pin2);

Comment: Just initialize the list firstly but do not add pins in customMap.Pins in  constructor ,  try to assign the value in method `APIConnection` .

Comment: I want to call APIConnection(pins); but I receive error in the constructor.. When I use APIConnection(customMap.CustomPins); I not receive error but method not work

Comment: What is the error message?